# SQL Server character for enclosing database, table, field names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a script to create a bunch of tables, and I read in the `<a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx">Microsoft documentation</a>` that I should use tick marks (aka grave) to enclose database, table, and field names, but when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio, I get a syntax error on the first tick:

```
CREATE TABLE `active`.`test` ( … )
             ^syntax error
```

So I tried running it thru a `<a href="http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml#parser">lint</a>`, and it told me that ` is an invalid character, and it suggested removing them, which totally messed up the script.

What gives?

Comment: You don't need to quote those names. Just remove those backticks. Quoting is only required if you are using reserved words or special characters in the name.

Comment: @Oded, oh, you're quite right. i meant grave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you have linked to is:

> The SQL query strings for **Windows Installer** are restricted to the following formats.

This is **not** the syntax for SQL Server. I suggest looking at the [Transact-SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826.aspx) instead.

You need to use `[]` instead of the backtick:

```
CREATE TABLE [active].[test]
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Until I saw it written as TSQL I thought it was just Microsoft's weird way of saying transaction-based SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Use square brackets...

```
CREATE TABLE [active].[test](...)
```